# El valor de mi vector de mi arreglo se cambia sin haber razón (c++)

Tags: dev-c++

El valor 0 de mi vector de mi arreglo "Datos" se cambia de valor al terminar el primer ciclo "for", cuando este no debería de cambiarse porque no hago el proceso. El valor cambia al de ultimo vector de otro arreglo. No sé porqué de esto.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string Datos[]= {"apellido paterno", "apellido materno", "nombre", "especialidad", "turno", "grupo", "semestre"};
    string respuestas[6];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
        cout<<"Inserte su "<<Datos[i]<<": ";
        cin>>respuestas[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
        Datos[i][0] = towupper(Datos[i][0]);
        cout<<endl<<Datos[i]<<": "<<respuestas[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu error está en la declaración del array `respuestas`. Si pones `[6]` le estás diciendo que tienes únicamente 6 elementos, cuando en realidad quieres guardar 7. Para decirle al compilador cuántos elementos tiene que reservar, en la declaración debes poner el número real de elementos que quieres, "sin tener en cuenta" el elemento[0] por así decirlo. Si lo declaras como `string respuestas[7];` tu problema se resuelve.

Comment: Deberías estar obteniendo un error porque no existe el elemento 6.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> se indexan desde cero, sus elementos están numerados desde *0* a *tamaño - 1*. En el caso de tu formación `respuestas` los índices válidos son `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` y `5` que como puedes contar son seis elementos, que coincide con el tamaño definido:

```
string respuestas[6];
```

Sin embargo tus bucles recorren los índices `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` y `6`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
```

Que como puedes contar son siete elementos.

---

El motivo por el que se te modifica el valor de `Datos` es porque acceder a valores de formaciones fuera de su rango es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) y como tal podría hacer que tu programa funcionase, o no funcionase o en caso de funcionar lo hiciera de manera errática.

Lo que creo que está pasando es que en memoria las formaciones `Datos` y `respuestas` están distribuidas de la siguiente manera:

| `respuestas[0]` | `respuestas[1]` | `respuestas[2]` | `respuestas[3]` | `respuestas[4]` | `respuestas[5]` | `Datos[0]` | `Datos[1]` | `Datos[2]` | `Datos[3]` | `Datos[4]` | `Datos[5]` | `Datos[6]` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | `apellido paterno` | `apellido materno` | `nombre` | `especialidad` | `turno` | `grupo` | `semestre` |

De manera que cuando escribes en la posición 6 de `respuestas` (posición que no existe) estás sobrescribiendo la posición 0 de `Datos`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
    cout<<"Inserte su "<<Datos[i]<<": ";
    cin>>respuestas[i]; // Cuando 'i' es 6 ==> Comportamiento indefinido
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.